# Some abundant text when inserting code into latex with listing

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex, listings

My lstset as below:

```latex
\lstset{ %
language = c++,
basicstyle = \footnotesize,
numbers = left,
numberstyle = \tiny\color{gray},
stepnumber = 2,
keepspaces = true,
numbersep = 5pt,
backgroundcolor = \color{white},
showspaces = false,
showstringspaces = false,
showtabs = false,
frame = single,
rulecolor = \color{black}
tabsize = 2,
captionpos = b,
breaklines = true,
breakatwhitespace = false,
title = \lstname,
keywordstyle = \color{blue},
commentstyle = \color{dkgreen},
stringstyle = \color{mauve},
escapeinside = {\%*}{*)},
morekeywords = {*,...}
}
```

and I insert my code through

```latex
\lstinputlisting{my.cc}
```

But I get this:

[image]

How can I obliterate the "Tabsize" at left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because you are missing a comma after the rulecolor line?

Comment: I've modified it but it does not make sense.

Comment: @Asuka: What do you mean by "it does not make sense"? Of course it's related since `tabsize` is the element following your `rulecolor`.

Comment: This answer can do with some authority... as it stands it's a questionable comment...

Comment: Perhaps you could display your new input and the result that you get.